# CTE with insert and update in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 and I want to know if I can use CTE with insert and update together e.g. if one condition fails then insert else update.

```
With X As
(
    Select COMP 
    From comp 
)
IF EXISTS (  Select * From  A Where A.COMP = X.COMP )

Insert Into A (COMP,comp1)
    select X.COMP, @COMP1 from X
Else
    Update A set comp1=@comp1 
    where comp= X.Comp
```

I have tried to use

```
 With X As
    (
        Select COMP 
        From comp 
    )

    Insert Into A (COMP,comp1)
        select X.COMP, @COMP1 from X
 With Y As
    (
        Select COMP 
        From comp 
    )
  Update A set comp1=@comp1 
  join Y on comp= Y.Comp
```

But if it is a insert then it is inserting the record and also it is executing the Update block . Can you tell me how to avoid that with If statement.

Comment: Have you even **tried** it yourself? Just go ahead!

Comment: You might want to check into `MERGE` command - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Comment: No, I dont want to use merge.

Comment: Yes, I have tried it and got error. If my code is wrong please tell me. If I can write like that or not.

Comment: Your code is wrong. You can not do an insert and an update in the same statement (unless you use merge). The CTE is available only in one statement.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `MERGE`? Business requirement?

Comment: I have used two with's also one for insert and another for update but still I am getting error. As I told before I dnt want to use merge.Is there any other way. Yes ,Business requirement

Answer (score 2):

As you can only use CTE once after it is declared, you cannot used it in both `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements.

As you cannot use `MERGE` due to constraints out of your control, as you say, you can use a temporary table instead:

```
Select COMP
into #temp
From comp 

IF EXISTS ( Select * From  A Where A.COMP = #temp.COMP )
    Insert Into A (COMP,comp1)
    select #temp.COMP, @COMP1 from #temp
Else
    Update A set comp1=@comp1 where comp= #temp.Comp
```

Answer (score 0):

A WITH clause can only be used with a single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statement. It cannot be used with an IF or any other statement. That you've already been told in comments.

The reason why your second attempt, where you are trying to use separate WITH clauses for INSERT and UPDATE, fails is probably because there is no semicolon at the end of the INSERT statement. The WITH keyword has multiple uses in Transact-SQL and sometimes it is expected in the middle of the statement while at other times it goes at the beginning. To avoid ambiguity, a semicolon is made mandatory (in SQL Server 2008 and later version) at the end of a statement if the next statement begins with a WITH clause.

But actually it would be a [good idea to get into the habit of using semicolons anyway](https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons).

So, this is how you should run these two statements together:

```
 With X As
    (
        Select COMP 
        From comp 
    )

    Insert Into A (COMP,comp1)
        select X.COMP, @COMP1 from X;  /* <-- this semicolon is required */
 With Y As
    (
        Select COMP 
        From comp 
    )
  Update A set comp1=@comp1 
  join Y on comp= Y.Comp;  /* <-- this one is optional,
                              but why not make things consistent? */
```